# How to control the life cycle of eclipse browser and monitor its HTML content change

Tags: java, eclipse, browser, eclipse-plugin

The scenario is that when I would like to launch the browswer pointing to some web pages in Eclipse Plugin and I would like to monitor the content change in the HTTP/S message and do some corresponding operations.
The corresponding operations may looks like fetch the raw field of HTTP/S message from browser.
For example, when users do some operations (AJAX) call and then the title or other fields of HTML page change, I would like to know this is happpening and fetch the "raw" content from the body field of HTTP/S message.

I found some ways to launch the browser here. The first one is that I could use SWT browser (org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser) here. However, I do not see it expose any listener API to monitor this change, let alone fetch raw content of HTTP/S message.

The second one is about org.eclipse.ui.browser.IWebBrowser. I also do not see any API expose by IWebBrowser.

Does anyone kwno how to do achieve this? Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This are no APIs for this.

The `Browser` class does have listeners for changes to the Location (`addLocationListener`) and the page title (`addTitleListener`) but these are fairly limited.